# Regular Expression to remove content before certain tag

Tags: regex

How do I remove content before certain tag/text, for example I wanna remove everything before this comment:

```
    <!-- article begins -->
```

and I wanna remove everything after

```
    <!-- article ends -->
```

Comment: Why do you need regex for these simple string operations?

Comment: -1 no language tag..its important to tag the language you are using with regex questions

Answer (score 1):

Python example (you didn't say which language you wanted):

```
import re
reobj = re.compile(".*?<!-- article begins -->(.*)<!-- article ends -->.*", re.DOTALL)
result = reobj.sub(r"\1", subject)
```

This also removes the tags. And it assumes that there is only one `article begins/ends` pair in `subject`.

Comment: Yea, I just wanted the regex because I'm using this "Advanced Find and Replace" utility that helps search and replace in files and supports regular expression also. The example you gave did not work with this tool, I probably have to see this utility's documentation for the exact syntax, Thanks.

Comment: Check your utility for an option that says "Dot matches newlines" or so. That must be activated. If you can't find it, add `(?s)` at the start of the regex. Why didn't you include this information in your question? If we're forced to guess, we can't give you reliable answers.

Answer (score 1):

**C#** (No need for Regex).

```
string start = "<!-- article begins -->";
string end = "<!-- article ends -->";

var article = text.Split(new string[] { start, end }, 
                         StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your regex engine. They almost all have a mode where you can ask "." to match all characters, including newlines. Then you'd capture the stuff you want:

```
.*article begins.....(.*).....article ends.*
```

I'm using dots for the comment markers, as some of those characters are special depending on your regex engine.

You might look at awk instead, it has a nicer way of doing this:

```
awk '/article begins/,/article ends/ { print }' filename
```

which designates a regex range with an action:

```
/start pattern/,/end pattern/ { action to do }
```

Answer (score 0):

With `sed`:

```
sed -n '/<!-- article begins -->/,/<!-- article ends -->/p' yourfile
```

It does not assume there is only one pair of matching tags